# Simpler way to write a java output to both console and text file?

Tags: java, file, filewriter

So im a pretty big noob at java and I have a exam coming up and have been practicing all week. My progress has been slow but steady. One exercise I am doing requires me to print the output of an array calculation to a console AND create a file `temperature.txt` with the console output and same formatting.

I've figured out how to be able to do one or the other but i'm having trouble doing both (remember slow and steady learner). Is there a simpler beginners method to keep in mind?

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Temperature {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{ 
        double[] temps = {100, 98, 80.5, 90.2, 99.4, 89.1};
        MaxMin(temps);

    }

    public static void MaxMin(double[]temps) throws IOException{
        FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter("Temperatures.txt", true);
        PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter(fwriter);
        double min= Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double max= Double.MIN_VALUE;
        double sum = 0;

        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.0");

        for(int i = 0;i<temps.length;i++){
            sum += temps[i];
            if(temps[i] > max){
                max = temps[i];
            }
            if(temps[i]< min){
                min = temps[i];
            }
        }

        double avg = sum / temps.length;
        outputfile.println("Average Temp: " + formatter.format(avg));
        outputfile.println("Maximum Temp: " + formatter.format(max));
        outputfile.println("Minimum Temp: " + formatter.format(min));
        outputfile.close();
    }
}
```

What I have above prints the text but nothing on the console.

edit: would it be acceptable to just add 3 System.out.println statements at the end to fulfill both requirements? like this:

```
System.out.println("Average Temp: " + formatter.format(avg));
System.out.println("Maximum Temp: " + formatter.format(max));
System.out.println("Minimum Temp: " + formatter.format(min));

outputfile.println("Average Temp: " + formatter.format(avg));
outputfile.println("Maximum Temp: " + formatter.format(max));
outputfile.println("Minimum Temp: " + formatter.format(min));
outputfile.close();
```

Comment: Use Logging. Log4j for Java. Console And Text Output in one

Comment: As for you're new edit, I would do one of two things for readability sake.  I would either make one big string with the newline characters embedded so you have a single console print and a single file write, or I would alternate so lines 1&2 write/print Avg Temp, lines 3&4 write/print max temp, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Commons IO has a [TeeOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) that writes everything to two outputs at once.

Comment: While it's a great answer for an engineering problem, possibly DarkD needs to write it himself, if it's for an exam... so looking at source would probably be better than using the library.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest in your case would be to create an `output` method:

```
private void output(final String msg, PrintStream out1, PrintWriter out2) {        
    out1.println(msg);
    out2.println(msg);
}
```

And using it like this:

```
output("your message", System.out, outputfile);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if it's important that the formatting be identical between console and file, then I'd save all of your output to a single `String`, embedding the `'\n'` characters and such, and then just print/write that `String` all in one go.

I don't know off hand whether or not there's a method for writing to both file and console at the same time.  You can always write a function that will do both of these things though.

Comment: lol I never thought about it that way. In terms of my problem it seems plausible to have both systemout and printwriter

ended up just adding system.out.println statements like this to the end

Answer (score 1):

**Log4j** is a Reliable, Fast and Flexible Logging Framework for console and file appending.

[Logging Example](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/log4j/log4j-example-multiple-appender.html) to append on Console and File togather!

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void MaxMin(double[] temps) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter("Temperatures.txt", true);
    PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter(fwriter);
    double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    double sum = 0;

    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.0");

    for (int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++) {
        sum += temps[i];
        if (temps[i] > max) {
            max = temps[i];
        }
        if (temps[i] < min) {
            min = temps[i];
        }
    }
    double avg = sum / temps.length;



    String str = "Average Temp: " + formatter.format(avg) + "\n"
            + "Maximum Temp: " + formatter.format(max) + "\n"
            + "Minimum Temp: " + formatter.format(min);
    System.out.println(str);
    outputfile.println(str);
    outputfile.close();

}
```

make a string and then print it twice, `\n` is a linebreak

Comment: if u want to print more then one string i would use the way epoch did http://stackoverflow.com/a/19107954/2441561